# If you mispronounce mantra, how can you fix the energy you created

Tags: mantras

i have heard that if you mispronounce mantra it can be dangerous, how do you fix this?

Comment: Few people say pronunciation does not matter as Guru give some energy. But few say every alphabet matters. In the end guru is the key for guidance. More experienced folks will give some comment on it.

Comment: That depends on your mantra and its type. Mispronouncing a beeja mantra would have problems, a shabar mantra would be somewhat okay. Vedic mantras would slow down the effect and stotram would definitely have no problem.

Comment: You can't fix it. Just change your pronunciation (to be more accurate) for the future.